# Neo4j Cypher return Map object

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Cypher query:

```
WITH {} as ceNodeIds 
WITH ceNodeIds {`Employment`: [6, 7, 8]} 
WITH ceNodeIds  
MATCH (root3:Location ) 
WHERE root3.id IN ([1, 2, 3]) 
WITH ceNodeIds, root3 OPTIONAL 
MATCH (root3)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant3:Location) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ascendant3:Location)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(root3) 
WITH ceNodeIds, COLLECT(root3.id) AS listRoot3, COLLECT( DISTINCT ascendant3.id) AS listAscendant3, COLLECT( DISTINCT descendant3.id) AS listDescendant3 
WITH ceNodeIds {`Location`: apoc.coll.union(listDescendant3, apoc.coll.union(listRoot3, listAscendant3))}  
WITH ceNodeIds 
RETURN ceNodeIds
```

as the result, I expect to receive a `Map` with two key/value pairs:

```
"Employment":[6, 7, 8]
"Location":[1,2,3,4,5]
```

but I only have there the one entry:

```
"Location":[1,2,3,4,5]
```

where have I killed the `Employment` key/value in this query, and what is the right way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to insert `.*` in the map projection at

```
WITH ceNodeIds {`Location`: apoc.coll.union(listDescendant3, apoc.coll.union(listRoot3, listAscendant3))}
```

so it reads:

```
WITH ceNodeIds {.*, `Location`: apoc.coll.union(listDescendant3, apoc.coll.union(listRoot3, listAscendant3))}
```

compare

```
WITH {} as ceNodeIds 
WITH ceNodeIds {`Employment`: [6, 7, 8]} 
WITH ceNodeIds {`a`:  4}
RETURN ceNodeIds
```

returning

```
╒═══════════╕
│"ceNodeIds"│
╞═══════════╡
│{"a":4}    │
└───────────┘
```

and

```
WITH {} as ceNodeIds 
WITH ceNodeIds {`Employment`: [6, 7, 8]} 
WITH ceNodeIds {.*, `a`:  4}
RETURN ceNodeIds
```

returning

```
╒════════════════════════════╕
│"ceNodeIds"                 │
╞════════════════════════════╡
│{"a":4,"Employment":[6,7,8]}│
└────────────────────────────┘
```